# Import edge direction from networkfile

Tags: cytoscape.js

I have a network file created using a tool developed by me, the network file looks like this

```
GeneA     GeneB     <-
GeneB     GeneC     ->
GeneD     GeneC     ->
GeneD     GeneF     <-
```

Importing the network itself was successfully done, but I am looking for a way to import the directions in the network. Since the directions are not always the same, can somebody tell me how to import such directions into cytoscape. I have looked a lot and could not find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Cytoscape.js you can put arrows to four different locations (see the [documentation](http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/edge-arrow) for more details).

The standard one for a directed graph would be arrows at the end of edge pointing towards to the `target` node. This can be  achieved by setting `target-arrow-shape` to a supported shape (such as `triangle`, `tee`, `vee` and etc.). You also need to set the `source` and `target` of each edge properly. In your example

```
GeneA     GeneB     <-
```

`GeneB` would be source and `GeneA` would be the target,

```
GeneB     GeneC     ->
```

`GeneB` would be source and `GeneC` would be the target and so on.

For different arrow types see [this example](http://js.cytoscape.org/demos/edge-arrows/).